# Customize Google Places Map API "icon" InfoWindows

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am having trouble customizing the  "clicked" infowindows in the google places API. I am able to use the places api to find locations and to customize the searched infoWindows (image 1) but I cannot seem to figure out how to customize the infoWindows launched by the places icons (image 2).

I apologize, part of my problem is I don't know what those specific infoWindows are called and if I did, I might be able to search for the solution.  It seems most questions on this site are related to customizing the searched infoWindow content and I have had success doing that.

[Searched Customized InfoWindow (image 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkIZE.png)

[The InfoWindow that I want to customize and is launched by icons on the map (image 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czooq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are called `clickableIcons`.  From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)

> **clickableIcons** | Type:  boolean
> When false, map icons are not clickable. A map icon represents a point of interest, also known as a POI. By default map icons are clickable.

and:

> **getClickableIcons()** | Return Value:  boolean
> Returns the clickability of the map icons. A map icon represents a point of interest, also known as a POI. If the returned value is true, then the icons are clickable on the map.

To control the InfoWindow, stop the default one from being opened, as described in the [IconMouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#IconMouseEvent) documentation:

> **google.maps.IconMouseEvent** object specification
>
> This object is sent in an event when a user clicks on an icon on the map. The place ID of this place is stored in the placeId member. **To prevent the default info window from showing up, call the stop() method on this event to prevent it being propagated.** Learn more about place IDs in the Places API developer guide.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zv06k2s/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(evt) {
    evt.stop()
    if (evt.placeId) {
      console.log(evt.placeId);
      iw.setContent(evt.placeId);
      iw.setPosition(evt.latLng);
      iw.open(map);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked!  Just another quick question, where can I see a list of available details from the infoWindow?  You have "placeID" and "latLng" which I need but I am also looking for the business name and maybe a rating if possible.

Comment: For more than that you will need to make a [PlaceDetails](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details) request.  Related question: [Google place Api PlaceDetails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580788/google-place-api-placedetails)